# arm assembly junk only on strings of length 12

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I encountered a strange problem while coding a linked list in arm assembly on the raspberry pi.  my linked list works for all strings except strings with a length of 12.  it displays a junk character at the end of all strings with a length of 12 and I cannot figure out why

any help is appreciated

here is the input function I'm using, it outputs the address to the malloc'd string in R0 and seems to function correctly for all strings not length 12:

```
.equ    BUFSIZE2,256

.data
inputbuf2:  .ds BUFSIZE2
prompt:     .asciz  "Enter: "
p1:     .word   0

input:
    push {R1,R2,R5,R14}
    mov R0,#0
    bl  v_ascz        @ prints string in R1
    ldr R1,=inputbuf2
    mov R2,#BUFSIZE2
    bl  c_ascz        @ does service call for input, returns in R1
    bl  v_ascz
    bl  v_nl
    bl  strlen        @ returns string length of R1 into R0
    sub R0,#1
    mov R5,R0
    bl  alloc
    bl  store
    ldr R0,=p1
    ldr R0,[R0]
    pop {R1,R2,R5,R14}
    bx  LR

alloc:
    push {R0-R4,R14}
    bl  malloc
    ldr R1,=p1
    str R0,[R1]
    pop {R0-R4,R14}
    bx  LR

store:
    push    {R1-R4,R14}
    mov R2,#0       @ index
    ldr R4,=p1
    ldr R4,[R4]
    loop:   ldrb    R3,[R1],#1
    strb    R3,[R4],#1
    add R2,#1
    cmp R2,R5
    blt loop

    mov R3,#0
    strb    R3,[R4]       @ store null at end of string
    pop {R1-R4,R14}
    bx  LR


.end
```

And here's the linked list add node function I'm using.  It allocates 8 bytes and stores the address to the data in the first four and the address to the next node in the last 4:

```
.global list_add
@   R1  =   addr of head
@   R2  =   addr of tail
@   R3  =   data
.data
node:   .word   0

list_add:
    push    {R1-R4,R14}
    bl  alloc
    push    {R2}
    ldr R2,[R2]
    cmp R2,#0
    pop {R2}
    beq first_node
            @ normal add
    ldr R4,=node
    ldr R4,[R4]
    push    {R2}
    ldr R2,[R2]     @ R2 = tail node
    str R4,[R2,#4]  @ R2 next ptr = node
    pop {R2}
    str R4,[R2]     @ tail = node
    str R3,[R4]     @ node data = first addr of data
    mov R3,#0
    str R3,[R4,#4]
    pop {R1-R4,R14}
    bx  LR

first_node:
    push    {R1-R4}
    ldr R4,=node
    ldr R4,[R4]
    str R4,[R1]     @ head = node
    str R4,[R2]     @ tail = node
    str R3,[R4]     @ node data = data
    mov R3,#0
    str R3,[R4,#4]
    pop {R1-R4}
    pop {R1-R4,R14}
    bx  LR

alloc:
    push    {R1-R3,R14}
    mov R0,#8
    bl  malloc
    ldr R1,=node
    str R0,[R1]
    ldr R1,[R1]
    mov R3,#0
    str R3,[R1]
    str R3,[R1,#4]
    pop {R1-R3,R14}
    bx  LR
```

Adding a bunch of random strings centered around my girlfriend's dog, wriggly, this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgAIQ.png).  ignore the numbers, they're the decimal addresses of the malloc'd memory

Comment: Use a debugger, check where the memory contents don't match what you assume them to be, go from there to figure out where the assumptions and code split - that's probably your bug. Going by the output alone, it seems your strings are not properly terminated.

Comment: Thank you I will keep trying!  The strings are null terminated and it really only happens on strings specifically length 12, I’ve tested a lot of different sizes so that’s really what’s stumping me!  I will continue digging though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings, by convention, are terminated by a zero byte called the 'termination character'.

When you call `strlen` you obtain the number of characters in the string, excluding the termination character that marks its end.  This causes two problems:

- When you loop to copy the string, you are not copying the termination character.  Your string will therefore end at the next byte in memory that happens to be a zero, which could be anywhere.  You're seeing the result of undefined behaviour: there's no reason why 12 characters should not work when other numbers do, it's just a consequence of your specific circumstances.
- If you were to add the termination character, you'd be overflowing your destination string buffer, because your call to `malloc` also doesn't allocate enough space for the termination character.

While I'm here, I might as well also refer you to the ARM ABI, and specifically [the part about the procedure call standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf).  While the ABI does not rule out using `r0-r3` for intermediate values, these registers (along with `r12`) are 'call-clobbered' so it is typical to use `r4-r11` for intermediate calculation.  Functions must preserve `r4-r11`, usually by using the stack.  Your use of `r5` to hold a function argument (to `store`) is therefore contrary to the ABI, so your `store` function would not be callable from ABI-compliant code; and your pushing/popping of `r1-r3` in several places is unnecessary if your callers also conform to the ABI.  Also of note is that the ABI requires 8-byte stack alignment across function calls in different translation units, so it's a good idea to get into the habit of pushing and popping even numbers of registers to maintain this.  (If you call a library function like `malloc` or `strlen` without ensuring 8-byte alignment, for example, you could run into undefined behaviour again.)

Comment: Thank you!  The 8 byte alignment probably has something to do with it.   The strlen function is of my own design and does work how you described.  Using on the string I just got from c_ascz, my user input service call function, it returns the string length plus 2 for some reason.  In all other circumstances it rwturns the string length without the null.  So after c_ascz I subtract one to have string length + 1 in R0.  I then malloc that.  Then at the end of the store function inside input, I do store the null terminator.  Like I said the junk really only appears on all strings of length 12

Comment: There's no magic to 12 though.  Perhaps try to find out where the +2 is coming from in your string length calculation, rather than just subtracting one and hoping for the best?

Comment: I did but I don’t have enough posts or whatever for it to count, thank you though!